# Dealing with single quotes in a dynamic query

Tags: jdbc

I'm building a query as a string in my application layer to be executed over jdbc.

The string is constructed as follows:

```
"SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ROOT_ID) as rows1 FROM DANIEL.UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN "
                + "WHERE "
                + "UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN.SOURCE_TABLE = 'STI.PHYSICIAN' AND "
                + "UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN.FIRST_NAME = '"
                + firstP.getFirstName()
                + "' AND "
                + "UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN.LAST_NAME = '"
                + firstP.getLastName()
                + "' AND "
                + "UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN.POSTAL_CODE = '"
                + firstP.getPostalCode() + "'";
```

This works fine, until we hit a doctor in our database containing a single quote, such as "JEANNE-D'ARC" as her first name. It turns the query into the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ROOT_ID) as rows1 
FROM DANIEL.UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN 
WHERE UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN.SOURCE_TABLE = 'STI.PHYSICIAN' 
AND UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN.FIRST_NAME = 'JEANNE-D'ARC' 
AND UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN.LAST_NAME = 'ANON' 
AND UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN.POSTAL_CODE = 'AAA AAA'
```

How can we resolve this?

EDIT: as I understand it, I should be using parameters as something. This query is going into a program and we can't necessarily control what doctor's names come in, so I guess this is a SQL injection vulnerability, right?

Comment: If Jeanne D'Arc is a doctor on your staff, then your patients have nothing to worry about! :-)

Comment: This is a Java question  - have you tried putting various combinations of '' and/or ''' into your string? Is there a QuotedString(My_String) function (or similar) in Java? This happens a lot with Irish names (O'Brien &c...). Try [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258270/java-replace-issues-with-apostrophe-single-quote-and-backslash-together).

Comment: I don't think it's a java question. I need to store JEANNE-D'ARC in my database, which requires running that select statement in the SQL through the java, but the statement breaks with teh apostrophe. I could with no problem at all remove or change the apostrophe, but I want to keep it and have it be able to be inserted.

Comment: You could try a shadow column - uppercase everything, remove spaces, accents and apostrophes - you have Name = "Jeanne D'Arc", SeachName = "JEANNEDARC" - that's what I do for Irish names. With computed columns now for many servers, no need to do any calculations at all.

Comment: Regardless of RDMS, it's always better to use prepared statements and bind variables in applications. There are many reasons for that, such as parsing time and server resources, data escaping, SQL injection , etc.

Comment: Yes, concatenating input to form SQL opens you up to SQL injection attack.  You should declare parameters in the SQL and pass input strings to those parameters.

Comment: @JackDouglas Why wasn't this question just migrated to SO?

Comment: @Colin that's a good question - as far as I can see no-one cast a close vote to migrate but perhaps that's just because they have aged away. I not usually going to mod migrate if there is no sign that's what the community wants, if that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can escape single quotes by using 2 single quotes, that way your query would work. I'm not sure about the java syntax for a replace but your query should look something like this

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ROOT_ID) as rows1 
FROM DANIEL.UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN 
WHERE UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN.SOURCE_TABLE = 'STI.PHYSICIAN' 
AND UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN.FIRST_NAME = 'JEANNE-D''ARC' 
AND UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN.LAST_NAME = 'ANON' 
AND UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN.POSTAL_CODE = 'AAA AAA'
```

instead of this

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ROOT_ID) as rows1 
FROM DANIEL.UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN 
WHERE UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN.SOURCE_TABLE = 'STI.PHYSICIAN' 
AND UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN.FIRST_NAME = 'JEANNE-D'ARC' 
AND UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN.LAST_NAME = 'ANON' 
AND UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN.POSTAL_CODE = 'AAA AAA'
```

In any case, as has been suggested parametrized queries or stored procedures should be investigated (again, i'm not sure how to parametrize queries in java) .

You should also be very careful about SQL injection, what happens for example if someone enters a name "';drop table patients;--" ? Suppose the line breaks are not sent to SQL as I would expect from your example you get this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ROOT_ID) as rows1 
FROM DANIEL.UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN 
WHERE UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN.SOURCE_TABLE = 'STI.PHYSICIAN' 
AND UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN.FIRST_NAME = ''; drop table patients;--ARC'     AND UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN.LAST_NAME = 'ANON'     AND UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN.POSTAL_CODE = 'AAA AAA'
```

[OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) is a good resource on security and has a resource on Java SQL injection and prepared statements [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java)

From that page:

> **Prepared Statements**
>
> Variables passed as arguments to prepared statements will
>   automatically be escaped by the JDBC driver.
>
> Example: ps.1

```
String selectStatement = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE userId = ? ";
PreparedStatement prepStmt = con.prepareStatement(selectStatement);
prepStmt.setString(1, userId);
ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: I tired with above but it doesn't escape the single quotes.                       String pt1 = "'Gov't, Public Services, & Community','Reeeeetail','Prol Services','Reeeeeal Estate','Restaurhhhhants'";                                  PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
   stmt.setString(1, pt1);
   ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();